# Tibia bot in python

Tags: python, bots, mmo

I am trying to code a simple bot for 7.6 tibia private server. My problem is that I don't know how to get a packet responsible for some action and if I'll have one I don't know how to send it to server.
Can you give me some tips?

Comment: Do you have any code snippets you have tried.

Comment: @Kathir No, I just saw some Delphi examples and it all uses `packet.dll`.